# Blender Script (slices.py) not working: keyword unrecognized

Tags: python, scripting

Digging around stackexchange if found just the thing I was looking for for my Blender project [object slicer script](https://blenderyard.wordpress.com/2014/10/17/contour-lines-as-in-maps/). The only thing - I can't get it to work. I keep getting these error messages:

[image]

> Python: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/Users/gutuser01/Documents/Value2Go/sailboat-lines.blend/Text", line
> 78, in    File
> "/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/3.2/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py",
> line 115, in **call**
> ret = _op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw) TypeError: Converting py args to operator properties: : keyword "interval" unrecognized

I run Blender 3.2.2 (3.2.2 2022-08-03) on Mac.

Also: please do not suggest using a simple shader for the line pattern effect, as I plant to make svg export of the lines.

Thanks.

Comment: You link to an article from 2014, Blender Python API has changed a lot since then and porting to the new versions may be tricky…

Comment: It’s a script for a rather old version of Blender, so you might run into other issues. But for a start: in line 57, replace `=` by `:`. That’s the new way of notating operator properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Sietse said right, change here:

1. `interval : bpy.props.FloatProperty(name="Slice Interval", default=1.0, min=0.01, max=100)`

and

2. change to this:

   `bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add( location=loc, rotation=rot)`

then it works

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked nicely!

Comment: you are welcome!